# Animating SVG from off the page

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, anime.js

I have a vision for an animation I would like to do, and being new to SVG I am not sure how to achieve this. Basically, I have an SVG with a few very simple shapes. I would like a few of them to come in from off the page and land where they belong.

The problem that I'm running into is that if I try to transform a shape from the direction I would like it to come from, it goes outside of the SVG viewport and can not be seen.
Is it possible to take a piece of the SVG and make it visible on the rest of the page?
If not, is it possible to create a div the same size and shape and animate that so that it lands in the correct spot every time?
The only thing that worries me about this is having it end up in a funky places on different device sizes.

As you can see, I already have an animation using `anime.js` that animates them in from outside the `viewbox`, but I think it would look pretty awesome if they could come from all the way off the page. [Here is my codepen](https://codepen.io/linxlatham/pen/xpMjzd).

Here's an example of what my animation looks like now:

```
var rect4 = anime({
    targets: '.rect-4',
    translateY: '-100%',
    translateX: '100%',
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    duration: 3000,
    delay: 3500,
    direction: 'reverse'
});
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just make overflow visible:

```
.title
  position: absolute
  top: 25%
  right: 30%
  color: white
  text-align: right
  width: 30%
  overflow: visible

#name-svg 
  width: 120%
  position: absolute
  right: 0%
  overflow: visible
```

https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/BJMVzB

Comment: So simple! Thanks so much! Also is there also a way to make sure the sections coming in aren't seen until they're supposed to be? Now they are starting in position and then going out and coming in. If I set their opacity to 0 then they go back to being invisible when the animation finishes.

Comment: There are many solutions. For example, (1) Alter the SVG so the elements start where you want. (2) start with the SVG invisible, then make it visible when the animation starts.